# command in docker-compose.yaml throwing errors

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-compose

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: project_build
    image: sig-project
    environment:
      PROJECT_NAME: "${PROJECT_NAME:-NullProject}"
    command: /bin/bash -c "init_project.sh"
    ports:
      - 7777:7777
    expose:
      - 7777
    volumes:
      - ./$PROJECT_NAME:/app/$PROJECT_NAME
      - .:/home/jovyan/work
    working_dir: /app
    entrypoint: "jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=7777 --allow-root --no-browser"
```

Above is my docker-compose.yaml.

The command doesn't run, I get this error:

```
Unrecognized alias: 'c', it will have no effect
```

Furthermore, it runs the jupyter notebook out of /bin instead of /app.

If I change the command to

```
command: "init_project.sh"
```

it fails silently, and if try to do something complicated like:

```
command: python init_project.py
```

then it gives me this:

```
 No such file or directory: /app/python
```

note: init_project.sh is just a bash script wrapper for init_project.py

so it seems that for some reason the commands are run in a way that I don't understand and from within the /app directory but without shell or bash.

I've been hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out what I'm missing here and I don't know what else to try.

I've found a variety of issues and discussions that are similar, but nothing seems to resolve it.

these are the contents of the working-dir /app:

```
#ls
Dockerfile  docker-compose.yaml docker_compose.sh  init_project.sh    poetry.lock        pyproject.toml
Makefile    create_poetry_lock.sh  docker_build.sh  init_project.py    install-poetry.py  poetry_lock_update.sh  test.sh
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Also posted in https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-use-command-in-compose-yaml/127427

Answer (score 1):

Your compose file looks weird to me!

1. You either have a docker image which container will be created with, or you have a `Dockerfile` present which builds the image and then container will be created with that image.

Based on what has been said above;

Why do you have both `image` and `build` attributes on your compose file?
If image is already available (e.g: postgreSQL, rabbitmq) then you don't need to build anything, just provide the image.
If there's no image, then please also add your `Dockerfile` to the quiestion.

2. Why are you trying to run `/bin/bash -c`?

You can simply add:

```
bash /path/to/ur/shell_script
```

Lastly, why don't you add your command in the `Dockerfile` with `CMD`?
What are `init_project.sh` and `init_project.py`? Maybe also share the content inside those files as well.
Also might be good to add `tree` output so we know how from where different commands are being executed.

Comment: thanks for the quick response and the feedback. this is my first time using docker, so I'm mostly in the copy template && test && modify && repeat phase of things. still trying to figure out the details. That being said, I removed the build portion, as the image is already built, and changed the command to "command: bash /app/init_project.sh", I get the same error: "No such file or directory: /app/bash
"

Comment: I don't want to add the command to the Dockerfile because the command is project specific while the image is used for multiple different projects

Comment: If you modify first question and add more detail I can help you. you need to build the image I guess, you usually specify the image if it's on docker registries like nginx, rabbitmq, redis and stuff, if it's your own project you also need to build a dockerfile next to your docker-compose. share your dockerfile and I'll help you through if you have any, if not, you need to write a dockerfile.

Comment: Also please share the output of `ls` command. so we know where is your docker-compose file and where is your project and all the stuff. I cannot help you fix `no such a file or directory` if I don't know where and how your files are.

Comment: thanks, I've built the image. I don't have a problem spinning up the container, but any command that normally works in shell doesn't work when declared in the docker-compose.yml. this is apparently because it's called from within the /app directory, i.e. the working directory. I can share the contents of the /app dir, but it's not going to be of any help because there shouldn't be any of the base level command folders in the /app folder. that's what the /bin folder is for.